# Add a column to a dataframe, skip pasting in rows with -

Tags: r

I have problem with merging.

I have 2 dataframes.

dataframe 1:

```
structure(list(row = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3), col = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5), 
    ltr = c("-", ".", ".", ".", ".", "Q", ".", "A", "R", "-", 
    ".", ".", ".", "T", ".")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

dataframe2:

```
structure(list(freq = c("0.76423", "0.76423", "0.03546", "0.43677", 
"0.76972", "0.45678", "0.23145", "0.56835", "0.23145")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to copy freq column from dataframe2 to dataframe1. 
I want to avoid pasting in few rows

if dataframe1 has ltr = "-" (skip that row and subsequent rows with same col value)

```
row col ltr freq
1    1   -   skip
2    1   .   skip
3    1   .   skip
1    2   .   0.76423
```

I tried loops but it didn't work.
The result should look like this

```
structure(list(row = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3), col = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5), 
    ltr = c("-", ".", ".", ".", ".", "Q", ".", "A", "R", "-", 
    ".", ".", ".", "T", "."), freq = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "0.76423", 
    "0.76423", "0.03546", "0.43677", "0.76972", "0.45678", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "0.23145", "0.56835", "0.23145")), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to group by 'col', create a logical column by checking the presence of `any` '-' in the 'ltr' column and `replace` the TRUE elements with the 'freq' from second dataset ('df2')

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(col) %>% 
   mutate(freq = if(any(ltr == "-")) NA else TRUE) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(freq = replace(freq, which(freq), df2$freq))
# A tibble: 15 x 4
#     row   col ltr   freq   
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
# 1     1     1 -     <NA>   
# 2     2     1 .     <NA>   
# 3     3     1 .     <NA>   
# 4     1     2 .     0.76423
# 5     2     2 .     0.76423
# 6     3     2 Q     0.03546
# 7     1     3 .     0.43677
# 8     2     3 A     0.76972
# 9     3     3 R     0.45678
#10     1     4 -     <NA>   
#11     2     4 .     <NA>   
#12     3     4 .     <NA>   
#13     1     5 .     0.23145
#14     2     5 T     0.56835
#15     3     5 .     0.23145
```

---

Or with `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'col', find the row index (`.I`) based on the logical expression, specify the index in `i`, and assign (`:=`) the values of 'freq' from 'df2' to create the 'freq' column in 'df1'.  By dedault, the positions that are not in the `i` will be filled with `NA`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, .I[all(ltr != "-")], col]$V1
df1[i1, freq := df2$freq]
df1
#    row col ltr    freq
# 1:   1   1   -    <NA>
# 2:   2   1   .    <NA>
# 3:   3   1   .    <NA>
# 4:   1   2   . 0.76423
# 5:   2   2   . 0.76423
# 6:   3   2   Q 0.03546
# 7:   1   3   . 0.43677
# 8:   2   3   A 0.76972
# 9:   3   3   R 0.45678
#10:   1   4   -    <NA>
#11:   2   4   .    <NA>
#12:   3   4   .    <NA>
#13:   1   5   . 0.23145
#14:   2   5   T 0.56835
#15:   3   5   . 0.23145
```

Comment: Thank you @Akrun! It works perfectly fine with this test data. But when I tried to use this on the original data it gives an error.  Error in x[list] <- values : replacement has length zero

Comment: @user11352627   That is possible if the number of elements of matching index are not the same from the second data.  You may need to correct on that.  Here, the assumption is that the second dataset have exactly the same number of datapoints as the  subset of rows in the first data

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun! I will check it.

Comment: @user11352627  One issue with the second data is that there is no info except the values.  So, it may be difficult to pinpoint from df2

Comment: Hello @akrun, It worked. I just had to change column names. Thank you!